# How to convert hashmap from android to dictionary in Python?

Tags: android, python

### Below is the code which is sent as Android response to Python

```
{key1=value1,key2=value2}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more.. what is the data in hashmap and what format you want to convert it to?

Comment: Data is in key value pair. I'm using Volley class in Android and all the responses are in hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

```
for kv in '{key1=value1,key2=value2}'[1:-1].split(','):
    key, value = kv.split('=')
    my_dict[key] = value
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I did this. It works. But I was looking for more _pythonic_ way for this.

Comment: @BharatBittu: Edit your Question and show a example of what you are looking?